# Git mergetool with Perforce

Tags: windows, git, merge, perforce

I am using Perforce to resolve file conflicts in Git.
To set this up, I ran

```
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd 'p4merge.exe \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"'

git config --global merge.tool p4merge
```

`p4merge` is available in the path.

When I run `git mergetool` after conflicts have arisen, `p4merge` issues the following error message:

```
Errors: "./myfile.BASE.7132.example" is an invalid file
"./myfile.LOCAL.7132.example" is an invalid file
"./myfile.REMOTE.7132.example" is an invalid file
"myfile.example is an invalid file
```

It is *not* taking the complete path of the files like `c:\users\abc\project\path\myfile.example` but seems to think they are in the root directory.

I am working on Windows.

How can I make Perforce to take correct paths of the files?

Comment: I think the p4merge tool would really prefer to have the full path, because the current directory of the p4merge tool is probably not the same as the directory where git is placing those files.

Comment: i saw that git puts those file in the same location as the file on which conflicts occurred.. i can manually use p4merge to do the merging.